# standing nearby elements in array - python

Tags: python

Fill the array with random numbers in interval from 1 till 5. Elements standing nearby. Example:

Array:
1 2 3 3 2 1

Out: 3

Example:

Array:
1 2 3 4 2 1

Out: no

Everything that we do on the Internet does not work correctly, for example, if there is 3 3 3 2 4 on the input, then 3 3 will be shown what needs to be done so that I do not know. I ask for help!

Comment: You should try to make your input an output valid python so it's not ambiguous. Saying out should be 3 3 is not clear. Do you want a list? That would make out  `[3,3]` as string? out would be `"3 3"`. As it is we're not sure what you want and have to guess.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to code:

```py
import random

mass = [random.randint(0, 5) for i in range(5)]
print("Array: ",mass)

a = []
for i in range(len(mass) - 1):
    if mass[i] == mass[i + 1]:
        if not mass[i] in a:
            a.append(mass[i])


print("Out =", a)
```

[code in online compilier](https://techiedelight.com/compiler/?~km_py_rsr)